# what does ^ mean when declaring a version of a library in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, semantic-versioning

I see the symbol `^` a lot when a version is declared in a flutter pubspec file. how is:

`http: ^0.13.3` different from `http: 0.13.3` or even this `http: '0.13.3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pub.dev` packages use [SemVer](https://semver.org/) or semantic versioning.

The `^` character means “**compatible with**”

So taking the example

> How is http: ^0.13.3 different from http: 0.13.3 or even this http: '0.13.3'

**Would mean  >=0.13.3 <1.0.0**

You can an explanation of all modifiers at [Semver cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/semver)

Comment: If I get you clear it means take any version between 0.13.3  and 1.0.0?

Comment: Less than 1.0.0, But yes you got the idea.

Comment: SO if I 0.13.3 without ^ it means to take the exact version 0.13.3?

Comment: Yes, do also refer the SemVer cheatsheet above its a great resource for all the various ways version resolution works

Comment: @Thanoss If the answer helped you, consider selecting an accepted answer this will help others with the same question on StackOverflow.

Comment: And if i have "any" instead of the version? What decides the used version?

Answer (score 1):

There are major, minor, and patch represent the different releases of a package.

npm uses the tilde `(~)` and caret `(^)` to designate which patch and minor versions to use respectively.

So if you see `~1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest patch version such as `1.0.4`. If you see `^1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest minor or patch version such as `1.1.0`.

But if in your npm package.json file you’re referencing a package that hasn’t reached `version 1.0` yet, using the caret symbol will only grab the patch version.

Source: https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/